# Javascript ajax innerhtml to return html input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax call to a PHP file which creates a pre-filled form of inputs.
I have used this method to replace the contents of a div with a new input element before, but currently it is returning nothing to the page. Firebug shows that the ajax call works and the response and html is 100% accurate, it is just not populating the div from:

```
 document.getElementById('editdiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText();
```

Replacing the xmlhttp.responseText with "Test" works. I'm not sure where to look to fix.

This question is a coded example of my problem without an answer either: [AJAX: getElementById().innterHTML not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526666/ajax-getelementbyid-innterhtml-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[responseText](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#response) is an attribute not function, i.e [xmlhttp.responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) not `xmlhttp.responseText()`, change to:

```
document.getElementById('editdiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: I've typed this so many times and I just read so many questions and I didn't notice I'd added (). Thanks.